# Why am i getting packet loss/lag randomly in rocket league withouit ping rising much?

Tags: networking, desktop-computer, gaming

ive been having an issue where while playing rocket league, ill randomly start lagging, slightly raising my ping say from 40 to 70, but it feels like it goes up to 200+ ping. im thinking its packet loss, but ive never been able to be sure of anything because my discord never lags at the same time as the game. this has been extremely annoying and calling my internet provider didnt help at all.

if someone could help me do some troubleshooting i really want to figure out what the problem is, this has been completely ruining my experience on like the only game i play for so long. My internet provider is Xfinity and im using the XB7 gateway.

It could also be a hardware issue causing this, since one thing i think im noticing, or it might be something im imagining: i think the problem is worse when i play in windowed fullscreen than normal fullscreen.